# NDK error: undefined reference with android.mk

Tags: android-ndk

i m trying to use a library from https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/ in my native code
and during a compilation i got  error: undefined reference (bad link of my extern library)
what s wrong with it ?

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libstk 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libstk.a
#LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES :=$(LOCAL_PATH)/stk
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := native-audio-jni

#LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native-audio-jni.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
native-audio-jni.cpp\
sqlite3.c\
mysqlite.h 

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libstk
# for native audio
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lOpenSLES
# for logging
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog
# for native asset manager
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -landroid

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Thank you

Comment: Didn't the error message say in which compilation unit the error occurred and which symbol it failed to reference? Please inlcude the full error message exactly as it was given to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to include necessary header files for the prebuilt static library. Add them inside your shared library module.